# Hadoop native library and snappy not loaded

Tags: hadoop, snappy

I'm trying to enable the Hadoop native library and the snappy library for compression in Hadoop 2.2.0, but I always end up with:

```
./hadoop/bin/hadoop checknative -a
Native library checking:
hadoop: false
zlib:   false
snappy: false
lz4:    false
bzip2:  false
```

I compiled `hadoop-2.2.0-src` from scratch for x64 and put the resulting `.so` in `hadoop/lib/native/`. I also compiled snappy from scratch and put it there. In a different approach I installed snappy via `sudo apt-get` and then linked the resulting `.so` to `hadoop/lib/native/libsnappy.so`, still no luck.

What is going on here? Why won't Hadoop find my native libraries? Is there any log where I can check what went wrong during loading?

Comment: have you tried `sudo ./hadoop/bin/hadoop checknative -a`